# Is $-706$ points for "user was removed" a new record?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I occasionally lose $10$ or $20$ reputation points for "user was removed", and maybe sometimes it's been as high as $50,$ but this time it's $706.$ Is that a new record?

Is it said that if the user who is removed has a very high reputation, then they don't deduct points because of it. What is the cutoff for that? And is there a cutoff for how many point can be deducted in such an event?

Comment: I lost 196. Curious... I wonder if it's the same user.

Comment: I lost "only" 175.  Of course it is the same user.  We could compare times.  Mine was yesterday at 01:11

Comment: Mine was at $01:11$ too. The deleted user has voted around 9k upvotes, so I guess I lot of users would be affected.

Comment: My loss was at that same time-stamp $01:11$

Comment: My record in one account is over 9000. What are you talking about? What you have is barely a reputation flesh wound...actually, barely a scratch considering your total.

Comment: @Nick : To me it didn't even feel like a scratch, but it was quite surprising because I'd never seen it anywhere near so big.

Comment: @Nick Is "over 9000" referencing the meme, or do you really have an alt account with that much rep lost at one point?

Comment: @Nick: Usually 9000 points removed mean reputation irregularities. You claimed to have not been suspended. Does that include your other accounts?

Answer (score 10):

No, on a per user basis it's not a new record, not even close. See the point-timeline of Brian M. Scott around end of March this year for a recent loss an order of magnitude higher.

Yes, for 'large' accounts votes are often preserved. Actually the criterion are the votes cast, not the points of the user, considering both the absolute number as well as the number of users being affected. The precise threshold are not public to the best of my knowledge.  See [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) :

Sometimes the votes are also deleted if there are many. The point is that if there might be a problem related to the votes, then of course they should be discarded.

> If, during review, it becomes apparent that the user is or ever was involved in voting fraud, the votes are discarded as they would normally be.

Now, I am given to understand that the implementation of this is very rigid. That is a minor irregularity in the distant past, will lead to complete invalidation.

I am pretty sure this is what happened, but per site moderators do not deal with such account deletions.

Comment: In Brian's case I think that there was some targeted voting (which is funny, since the account is dormant). So I don't think it counts, otherwise we can also count all the voting fraud deletions...

Comment: I partly agree, which is why I added the "on a per user basis". That said, due to the same deletion end of March André Nicolas lost more than 1k, too. So it becomes not  very clear what does or does not count. Anyway, it's a bit of a pathological record, so I think it may be best not to dwell on it (which is why I removed a comment on OP around that).